# Cycles renders a random alternate perspective

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I have a strange problem I cant find remedied here or anywhere online.
In the Eevee viewport (where I set my camera up) my meshes appear exactly as I intend to render them. When switching to Cycles however, the mesh randomly appears really far off in the BG (and there's that strange circle around my render port view).
See below.
Any thoughts?
My render set up can be seen in the work panel.
And please forgive the blurred appearance of my mesh - it's not my model and I'm not in a position to share it.

[image]

Comment: Looks like your camera is set to *Fisheye Equisolid* (a *Panoramic* lens type in settings). Since Eevee doesn't yet support this lens type, it reverts to the standard perspective projection.

Comment: @HISEROD that is an answer, and appears correct.

Comment: @HISEROD - Thank you, mate. Wonderful to have your insight. Thank you!